# Using Naoqi C++ SDK without qibuild

Tags: c++, cmake, sdk, pepper

I am trying to use Pepper's C++ SDK without qibuild and the toolchain. I could not find any example. How can I use CMake file instead of qibuild? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Some years ago I was used to CMake and lazy to switch to qibuild, so I manage to compile using my old CMakeFiles. My binary seems ok, but I got random crashes, when compiled with qibuild, they were running fine. So I suggest you to try qibuild...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `make` without qibuild by first loading the right environment variables via the ctc :

```
source <path_to_your_naoqi_ctc>/yocto-sdk/environment-setup-core2-32-sbr-linux
```

then you can use ./configure and make...

It may also work with cmake, though I have not tested.

Also, as Mizux says, qibuild is built on top of cmake, so you might be able to tweak things to point to the right places (SDK paths and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't !
Please note that `qibuild` is based on CMake (not Modern CMake).

If you don't want to use the SDK you could just use the cmake toolchain but I think it's not publicly available ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to use a third party SDK with Pepper. I am looking this webpage(http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/tools/developing-using-thirdparty.html) but it does not really help. Is there better tutorial for using third party packages with Pepper?